# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: could not serialize access due to read/write dependencies among transactions

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

**UPDATE**: I managed in the end to reproduce this in a minimal setting which I posted as a [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21759739/274677).

I 've encountered the following exception when doing JDBC inserts from two different applications running side-by-side on the same PostgreSQL instance and tables:

```
 org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: could not serialize access due to read/write dependencies among transactions
 [java] ERROR>  Detail: Reason code: Canceled on identification as a pivot, during write.
 [java] ERROR>  Hint: The transaction might succeed if retried.
```

The exception occurred when trying to execute the following statement:

```
public int logRepositoryOperationStart(String repoIvoid, MetadataPrefix prefix, RepositoryOperation operation, int pid, String command, String from_XMLGregCal) throws SQLException {
    Connection        conn = null;
    PreparedStatement ps   = null;
    try {
        conn = getConnection();
        conn.commit();
        String SQL = "INSERT INTO vo_business.repositoryoperation(ivoid, metadataprefix, operation, i, pid, command, from_xmlgregcal, start_sse)  "+
                     "(SELECT ?, ?, ?, COALESCE(MAX(i)+1,0), ?, ?, ?, ? FROM vo_business.repositoryoperation                                      "+
                     "WHERE ivoid=? AND metadataprefix=? AND operation=?)                                                                         ";
        ps = conn.prepareStatement(SQL);
        ps.setString(1, repoIvoid);
        ps.setString(2, prefix.value());
        ps.setString(3, operation.value());
        ps.setInt   (4, pid);
        ps.setString(5, command);
        ps.setString(6, from_XMLGregCal);
        ps.setInt   (7, Util.castToIntWithChecks(TimeUnit.SECONDS.convert(System.currentTimeMillis(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)));
        ps.setString(8, repoIvoid);
        ps.setString(9, prefix.value());
        ps.setString(10, operation.value());
        if (ps.executeUpdate() != 1) { // line 217
            conn.rollback();
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
        conn.commit();
        return getMaxI(conn, repoIvoid, prefix, operation);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        conn.rollback();
        throw e;
    } finally {
        DbUtils.closeQuietly(conn, ps, (ResultSet) null);
    }

}
```

.. on line marked with `line-217` above. I provide the actual stack trace at the end.

The transaction isolation level for the `Connection` `conn` object is set to `SERIALIZABLE` in the implementation of `getConnection()`:

```
protected Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
    Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
    conn.setAutoCommit(false);
    conn.setTransactionIsolation(Connection.TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE);
    return conn;
}
```

It is likely that another application was also trying to write on the same table at the same time, though it certainly provided a different `operation` field so I don't see how any mixup could have occurred. Moreover, this is a single atomic insert so I don't see how access serialization comes into play.

What kind of error is this and how should I go about in trying to troubleshoot this? Should I be looking at transaction isolation levels, whole-table vs. row-specific locks (if there is such a concept in PostgreSQL), etc.? Should I just retry (the hint says that "The transaction might succeed if retried."). I'll try to reproduce it in a SSCCE but I 'm just posting this in case it has an obvious cause / solution

```
 [java] ERROR>org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: could not serialize access due to read/write dependencies among transactions
 [java] ERROR>  Detail: Reason code: Canceled on identification as a pivot, during write.
 [java] ERROR>  Hint: The transaction might succeed if retried.
 [java] ERROR>  at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2102)
 [java] ERROR>  at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1835)
 [java] ERROR>  at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:257)
 [java] ERROR>  at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:500)
 [java] ERROR>  at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:388)
 [java] ERROR>  at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeUpdate(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:334)
 [java] ERROR>  at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105)
 [java] ERROR>  at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105)
 [java] ERROR>  at _int.esa.esavo.dbbusiness.DBBusiness.logRepositoryOperationStart(DBBusiness.java:217)
 [java] ERROR>  at _int.esa.esavo.harvesting.H.main(H.java:278)
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Whenever you request `SERIALIZABLE` isolation the DB will attempt to make concurrent sets of queries *appear to have executed serially* in terms of the results they produce. This is not always possible, e.g. when two transactions have mutual depenencies. In this case, PostgreSQL will *abort one of the transactions* with a serialization failure error, telling you that you should retry it.

Code that uses `SERIALIZABLE` must always be prepared to re-try transactions. It must check the `SQLSTATE` and, for serialization failures, repeat the transaction.

See [the transaction isolation documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/transaction-iso.html).

In this case, I think your main misapprehension may be that:

> this is a single atomic insert

as it is nothing of the sort, it's an `INSERT ... SELECT` that touches `vo_business.repositoryoperation` for both reading and writing. That's quite enough to create a potential dependency with another transaction that does the same, or one that reads and writes to the table in another way.

Additionally, the serializable isolation code can under some circumstances de-generate into holding block-level dependency information for efficiency reasons. So it might not necessarily be a transaction touching the same rows, just the same storage block, especially under load.

PostgreSQL will prefer to abort a serializable transaction if it isn't sure it's safe. The proof system has limitations. So it's also possible you've just found a case that fools it.

To know for sure I'd need to see both transactions side by side, but here's a proof showing an `insert ... select` can conflict with its self. Open three `psql` sessions and run:

```
session0: CREATE TABLE serialdemo(x integer, y integer);

session0: BEGIN TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;

session0: LOCK TABLE serialdemo IN ACCESS EXCLUSIVE MODE;

session1: BEGIN TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;

session2: BEGIN TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;

session1: INSERT INTO serialdemo (x, y)
          SELECT 1, 2
          WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM serialdemo WHERE x = 1);

session2: INSERT INTO serialdemo (x, y)
          SELECT 1, 2
          WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM serialdemo WHERE x = 1);

session0: ROLLBACK;

session1: COMMIT;

session2: COMMIT;
```

session1 will commit fine. session2 will fail with:

```
ERROR:  could not serialize access due to read/write dependencies among transactions
DETAIL:  Reason code: Canceled on identification as a pivot, during commit attempt.
HINT:  The transaction might succeed if retried.
```

It's not the same serialization failure as your case, and doesn't prove that *your* statements can conflict with each other, but it shows that an `insert ... select` isn't as atomic as you thought.

Comment: So, is SERIALIZABLE maybe putting the bar too high? Should I opt for a lower transaction isolation setting (since PostgreSQL also defaults to "Read commited" which is two notches down from "serializable"). I am also concerned when a platform, any platform, is asking me to retry. If it were 100% correct to always retry, then I don't see why the DB can't retry instead. Therefore, I am not sure I should blindly retry.

Comment: @MarcusJuniusBrutus The DB can't retry because it hasn't kept a record of all the SQL statements you did up to this point, and it aborts the whole transaction, not just the current statement. It expects you to remember the work you want to do and replay it. That's what the spec says to do, and it means the DB doesn't have to pay the cost of remembering a series of statements in the vastly-most-common case of a normal commit.

Comment: Regarding your comment on not being a single atomic insert I am not sure that's correct. It's an atomic statement. It's not like a separate select and a separate insert (which is the example that appears here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/transaction-iso.html). As a matter of fact I did try to narrow it down with exactly the same INSERT/SELECT clause structure (without the domain-specific particulars) and I couldn't reproduce it even under heavy load. Part of the problem is that when debugging it PostgreSQL doesn't tell you which was the OTHER transaction / statement.

Comment: @MarcusJuniusBrutus There's no easy-out for concurrent behaviour except `LOCK TABLE ... IN EXCLUSIVE MODE`. If you lower the isolation level you don't have serialization failures but you do get to deal with the allowable transaction anomalies in read committed mode, which allows a variety of fun race conditions. (BTW, yes, I agree it sucks that it doesn't tell you what the other statement was like it does in deadlock resolution. The problem is that it isn't another *statement*, it's another *transaction*.)

Comment: @MarcusJuniusBrutus Actually, your statement it's a lot like a separate select and separate insert - it creates a read-write dependency in `SERIALIZABLE` isolation, and the `SELECT` occurs before the `INSERT`. The "Atomicity" of ACID refers to *atomic commit*, remember, it isn't an automatic out for concurrency issues .

Comment: @MarcusJuniusBrutus Added a test to the answer showing this, though admittedly not for your exact statements since you haven't shown the table definitions, params, etc.

Comment: in the end I managed to reproduce this in a minimal setting. See update at the beginning of the question.

Comment: You mentioned that under some circumstances serializable isolation can de-generate into holding block-level dependency information for efficiency reasons. Is there an article I can read about this?