# could not serialize access due to read/write dependencies among transactions

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I managed in the end to reproduce the serialization problem in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21706858/274677) to an SSCCE (Shortest Self-Contained Complete Example). I am using the `jdbc` and `java` tags although I believe this is not Java or JDBC-specific.

So, I am having two tables MASTERTABLE and DETAILTABLE. Rows in DETAILTABLE hang under rows in the MASTERTABLE:

```
CREATE TABLE public.MASTERTABLE(typename VARCHAR, i INTEGER);
ALTER TABLE public.MASTERTABLE ADD PRIMARY KEY (typename, i);

CREATE TABLE public.DETAILTABLE(typename VARCHAR, i INTEGER, j INTEGER);
ALTER TABLE public.DETAILTABLE ADD PRIMARY KEY (typename, i, j);
ALTER TABLE public.DETAILTABLE ADD CONSTRAINT detail_2_master FOREIGN KEY (typename, i) REFERENCES public.MASTERTABLE(typename, i);
```

Then I have code (appended in the end) which does the following in an endless loop:

1. inserts  a row in the master table with a given `typename`
2. inserts 100 rows in the detail table under the master table row added in step #1.

When I launch the code in two separate instances, running concurrently, with different `typename` parameters (say one is using `type-a` and the other `type-b`) after a few minutes I get the "`could not serialize access due to read/write dependencies among transactions`" message (trace at the end).

What I don't get is why is PostgreSQL confused about the two concurrent transactions since they are obviously accessing different "slices" of the table:

- One instance is reading and writing rows with a `typename` value of "`type-a`"
- The other instance is reading and writing rows with a `typename` value "`type-b`"

Furthermore, PostgreSQL knows that the `typename` is part of the primary key of both master and detail tables so the sets of rows accessed are guaranteed to be disjoint.

I append below the code, a typical invocation that causes the error, and the trace thrown.

## code

If the code below is modified to use a transaction isolation level of `Connection.TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ` instead of `Connection.TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE` the erroneous condition is not triggered. I did not include code to empty the tables prior to a re-run as I was trying to keep this as short as possible.

```
import javax.sql.*;
import java.sql.*;
import org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource;
import org.apache.commons.dbutils.DbUtils;

public class FooMain {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        String typeName       =                 args[0];
        Integer transIsoLevel =    Connection.TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE; 

        DataSource ds = getDataSource("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/your-database", "your-user-name", "your-user-password");
        Testing testingAPI = new Testing(ds, transIsoLevel);
        for (int i = 0 ; i < 1000*1000 ; i++) {
            System.out.printf("%s - %d\n", typeName, i);
            testingAPI.addMasterRow(typeName, i);
            for (int j = 0 ; j < 100 ; j++)
                testingAPI.addDetailRow(typeName, i);
        }
    }

    public static DataSource getDataSource(String dbURL, String user, String pwd) {
        BasicDataSource dS = new BasicDataSource();
        dS.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        dS.setUsername(user);
        dS.setPassword(pwd);
        dS.setUrl(dbURL);
        dS.setMaxActive(1);
        dS.setMaxIdle(1);
        dS.setInitialSize(1); 
        dS.setValidationQuery("SELECT 1");
        return dS;
    }
}


class Testing {

    private DataSource ds;
    private int transactionLevel;

    public Testing(DataSource ds, int transactionLevel) {
        this.ds           = ds;
        this.transactionLevel = transactionLevel;
    }


    private Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
        conn.setAutoCommit(false);
        conn.setTransactionIsolation(transactionLevel);
        return conn;
    }

    public void addMasterRow(String typeName, int i) throws SQLException {
        Connection conn = getConnection();
        PreparedStatement ps1 = null;
        ResultSet         rs1 = null;
        PreparedStatement ps2= null;

        try {
            conn.commit();
            {   // this select statement does nothing, but I believe it is needed
                // to trigger the error
                String SQL="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM public.mastertable  "+
                           "WHERE typename=?                         ";
                ps1 = conn.prepareStatement(SQL);
                ps1.setString   (1, typeName);
                rs1 = ps1.executeQuery();
            }
            {
                String SQL="INSERT INTO public.mastertable(typename, i)               "+
                           "VALUES(?, ?)                                              ";
                ps2 = conn.prepareStatement(SQL);
                ps2.setString   ( 1, typeName);
                ps2.setInt      ( 2, i);
                ps2.executeUpdate();
            }
            conn.commit();
        } finally {
            DbUtils.closeQuietly(             conn, ps1,              rs1);
            DbUtils.closeQuietly((Connection) null, ps2, (ResultSet) null);
        }
    }

    public void addDetailRow(String typeName, int i) throws SQLException {
        Connection conn = getConnection();
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        try {
            conn.commit();
            String SQL="INSERT INTO public.detailtable(typename, i, j)              "+
                       "(SELECT ?, ?, COALESCE(MAX(j)+1,0) FROM public.detailtable  "+
                       "WHERE typename=? AND i=?)                                   ";
            ps = conn.prepareStatement(SQL);
            ps.setString   ( 1, typeName);
            ps.setInt      ( 2, i);
            ps.setString   ( 3, typeName);
            ps.setInt      ( 4, i);
            ps.executeUpdate();
            conn.commit();
        } finally {
            DbUtils.closeQuietly(conn, ps, (ResultSet) null);
        }
    }
}
```

## invocation

Just invoke concurrently two instances, one with a command line argument of 'type-a' and the other with a command line argument of 'type-b':

```
java -classpath ... FooMain type-a &
java -classpath ... FooMain type-b &
```

## trace

```
Exception in thread "main" org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: could not serialize access due to read/write dependencies among transactions
Detail: Reason code: Canceled on conflict out to pivot 4720754, during read.
Hint: The transaction might succeed if retried.
Where: SQL statement "SELECT 1 FROM ONLY "public"."mastertable" x WHERE "typename"::pg_catalog.text OPERATOR(pg_catalog.=) $1::pg_catalog.text AND "i" OPERATOR(pg_catalog.=) $2 FOR SHARE OF x"
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2102)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1835)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:257)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:500)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:388)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeUpdate(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:334)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105)
at Testing.addDetailRow(FooMain.java:98)
at FooMain.main(FooMain.java:18)
```

Comment: Do you actually need [`TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE) behaviour? (BTW: There is a constant for that, no need to hardcode a value!).

Comment: It's not very obvious to me how one should decide whether he "really needs" TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE. The way I see, that's the only mode that guarantees that no kind of weird conditions (phantom reads, etc.) can occur so why not ask for that?, esp. when it's clear from a business logic perspective that the transactions really affect disjoint 'partitions' of the table, so PostgreSQL shouldn't have had a problem.

Comment: For most types of transactions you really do not need serializable, and in PostgreSQL read committed is essentially a snapshot of the start of the transaction; the issue of phantom reads don't normally occur. And given its MVCC architecture, you rarely run into issues that serializable is intended to solve. See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/transaction-iso.html

Comment: Inter-transaction dependency tracking is somewhat coarse, IIRC; I'd need to re-read the docs and study the sources to be sure what's going on, but I suspect what you're seeing is dependencies that share an index or heap block.